# How to properly refactor repeated code of 2 ViewControllers?

Tags: swift, delegates, uikit, refactoring, swift-protocols

I have 1 UIViewController with a type of CustomTableView and 1 UITableViewController with a type of usual UITableView. Both conform to `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` and implemented its delegate methods with the repeated code. For now it's in extensions.

Is it possible to move that code out to a separate swift file? I tried to move it to separate file with class NSFetchedResultsView, but when I copy that delegate methods to the new file, it doesn't know anything about tableView inside it's methods...

How can I separate that methods properly?

Delegate methods I want to separate:

```
func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    tableView.endUpdates()
}

func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
    switch type {
    case .update:
        if let indexPath = indexPath {
            tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
        }
    case .move:
        if let indexPath = indexPath, let newIndexPath = newIndexPath {
            tableView.moveRow(at: indexPath, to: newIndexPath)
        }
    case .delete:
        if let indexPath = indexPath {
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
        }
    case .insert:
        if let newIndexPath = newIndexPath {
            tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: .none)
        }
    default:
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an object that you can assign to be the delegate

```
class CommonFetchResultDelegate: NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {
    var tableView: UITableView

    // make init that takes the table view
    init(tableView: TableView) {
        self.tableView = tableView
    }

    // !!!implement all the other delegate functions!!!

    func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        tableView.beginUpdates()
    }

    func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }

    func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
        switch type {
        case .update:
            if let indexPath = indexPath {
                tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
            }
        case .move:
            if let indexPath = indexPath, let newIndexPath = newIndexPath {
                tableView.moveRow(at: indexPath, to: newIndexPath)
            }
        case .delete:
            if let indexPath = indexPath {
                tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
            }
        case .insert:
            if let newIndexPath = newIndexPath {
                tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: .none)
            }
        default:
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}


// then in the view controller 
var myDelegate: CommonFetchResultDelegate?

override viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.myDelegate = CommonFetchResultDelegate(tableView: self.tableView)
    self.myDelegate = fetchResultController.delegate
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I receive a warning: Cannot declare conformance to 'NSObjectProtocol' in Swift; 'CommonFetchResultDelegate' should inherit 'NSObject' instead. How can I fix it?

Comment: @artexhibit `class CommonFetchResultDelegate: NSObject, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`

Comment: got it. Thank you very much

Comment: @jnpdx beat me to it. The warning is telling you that there is a requirement that the delegate has to be an NSObject.